# Windows ISC Bind not listening on IPv6

Tags: windows, bind, windows-10

I have ISC Bind 9.10.4-P1 (named) running on Windows 10, with the following configuration file:

```
key "rndc-key" {
    algorithm hmac-md5;
    secret "jqTFmyJ3pGkoV4wC/yV9BQ==";
};

options {
    directory "C:\Program Files\ISC BIND 9\etc";
    listen-on {
        127.0.0.1;
    };
    listen-on-v6 {
        ::1;
    };
    allow-query {
        localhost;
    };
    forwarders {
        2001:4860:4860::8888;
        2001:4860:4860::8844;
        8.8.8.8;
        8.8.4.4;
    };
    recursion yes;
    dnssec-validation no;
    auth-nxdomain no;
};

view local {
    match-clients {
        localhost;
    };

    zone "test.local" {
        type master;
        file "zones/test.local.zone";
    };
};
```

This is what it appears to be listening on (`netstat /a /n /o | findstr $PID`):

```
TCP    127.0.0.1:53           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       1440
TCP    127.0.0.1:953          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       1440
TCP    [::1]:953              [::]:0                 LISTENING       1440
UDP    127.0.0.1:53           *:*                                    1440
```

I checked the Event Viewer and there are no errors or warning at startup, only the normal messages.

Does anyone have any idea why it does not listen on ::1?

**EDIT**:
If I put `any` at `listen-on-v6`, it kind of works. Listens on all IPv6 IPs bound to the machine, except ::1...

Comment: Which version of bind? Where did you get it? Why on earth are you running it on Windows 10?

Comment: Bind 9.10.4-P1. Well, to manage the hell of concurrent VPN connections with split DNS I need to run for all my customers :(.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've resolved this issue before by making sure proper reverse and forward dns entries are set up for localhost and ::1

In other words, configure the localhost zone to (also) return "::1" for queries to localhost and have the 1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.ip6.arpa zone set up to return a pointer for ::1  to "localhost."

Bind will ignore binding to ::1 otherwise.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.ip6.arpa.` which has a dot at the end?

Comment: ;-)  In the reference above it's a zone file name - you can call it what you wish in your config files - but you would reference it as that without a period like:

Comment: zone "1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.ip6.arpa" {
        type master;
        file "c:\dns\var\named\reverse\db.ipv6-rev-loopback";
 notify no;
};